# how to Restore IAP for non-consumable product in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, in-app

I want to know that 
**do one have to put two buttons separate one for Upgrade and Other for Restore for restore previous transactions??**

What steps should be taken by my self to avoid reject chances of App for Restore transaction.

I used below code for restore non-consumable In App Purchase.
If any changes in below code please let me know.

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
                // Call the appropriate custom method for the transaction state.
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                [self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:NO];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                [self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:YES];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                // For debugging
                NSLog(@"Unexpected transaction state %@", @(transaction.transactionState));
                break;
        }
    };


}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Restore Completed Transactions Failed WithError...%@",error);
    [self failedMessage:@"Restore Completed Transactions Failed"];
    [self stopIndicator];
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSMutableArray *arrPurchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        [arrPurchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];

        NSLog(@"arrPurchasedItemIDs : %@",arrPurchasedItemIDs);
    }

    NSLog(@"Restore Completed");
    [self completeMessage:@"Restore Completed"];
    [self stopIndicator];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can separate the Restore purchase code :

```
-(void)doClickRestore {
    [APP_DEL doStartSpinner];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
                // Purchase success Transaction
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
                // Purchase fail Transaction
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                [self doStopSpinner];
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self doStopSpinner];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

**Note :**

Clicking on Restore purchases will restore all purchased non consumable inApp purchases

Hope it will helps.

These below two mehods are optional but if you want you can use it.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error 


- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

Comment: Rather than calling `doStopSpinner` twice for each restored transaction, you should call it once in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`

Comment: @Paulw11 appreciate your solution..Good Idea

Comment: @Paulw11 do one have to put two buttons separate one for Upgrade and Other for Restore for restore previous transactions??

If user delete app and install app again then we do not know user purchase IAP or not. I think One should put two buttons one for Upgrade and Second for Restore.

am I right?

Comment: @Paulw11 I run app in iPhone through xcode and I purchased non consumable product and I got receipt data through [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL
but 
when i delete my app run again app and when i call [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL but i did not get receipt data  I got nil

Comment: @AnkurPatel yes as per apple rules you should put a separate button for Restore purchases somewhere in the app

Comment: @Mayur thanks I got it I visit apple site https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204530

Thanks for your support

Comment: @Mayur  I run app in iPhone through xcode and I purchased non consumable product and I got receipt data through [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL but when i delete my app run again app and when i call [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL but i did not get receipt data I got nil

Comment: @Mayur can we use this  [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL  for restore non consumable product ???

I [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL use this for subscription product

Comment: @Mayur and Pauiw11 Thanks for knowledge sharing Thanks for your valuable time. Mayur thanks for +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184444/discussion-between-ankur-patel-and-mayur).